# Hot wire goes dead when connected to a switch

Tags: electrical, switch, light

So I have a switch that went dead one day. I took out the switch and used my voltage tester to see if there was any power to line and load or really any of the lines. All the lines had no power. I checked the breaker and it was fine. I have another light going through that breaker and it is working fine. Once I disconnected the lines to the switch I checked again and saw now the line wire has power. I hooked up another switch just in case and found the line wire went cold again. No beeping from the tester. Again once I disconnected that wire from the switch and the other lines it had power. I have no idea what’s causing this. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: As you are new, try reading your post: it is difficult to follow and lacks facts necessary to help.   Photographs can be helpful.   A circuit diagram would certainly help frame your question.   You should be measuring voltage (110 / 220) and not rely on beeping

Comment: The loss of power when connecting/moving the wire sounds like the wire is broken inside of the insulation.  This can be dangerous if you are only going by beeping to tell of no power instead of turning off the breaker to play with live wires.